# How to write all PowerShell screen output to .csv report file

Tags: windows, powershell

[Fig1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YiLo2.png)    [Fig2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKmvL.png)   While I know this is a similar to many other questions regarding this, however, I have been having a difficult time figuring out how to make what I see on the screen go to the output file. I'm using PowerShell Version 5.1.16299.1146. Fig1 image is what I see on the PS screen. I want the script to see if a particular file is present and if it is TRUE or FALSE, write the information to the .csv file. Fig2 image is what actually gets written to the .csv report. I want the computer Name, Results (TRUE/FALSE), and Users + LastWriteTime written to the .csv file if it is found in the user's AppDate location for each user on a particular machine.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass
$javausers = @()
$env:COMPUTERNAME = HostName

$TestPath = "$env:userprofile\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\deployment.properties"
$TestResult = if ( $(Try { Test-Path $TestPath.trim() } Catch { $false }) ) { Write-Output "True - deployment.properties" } Else { Write-Output "False - Path not found" }

$users = Get-ChildItem c:\users

foreach ($user in $users)
{

$folder = "C:\users\" + $user + "$env:userprofile\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\deployment.properties" 

if ( $(Try { Test-Path $TestPath.trim() } Catch { $false }) ) { Write-Output "True - deployment.properties" $users -join ','} Else { Write-Output "False - Path not found" $users-join ','}

}

$javauser = New-Object System.Object
$javauser | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Computer Name" -Value $env:COMPUTERNAME
#$javauser | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Java User" -Value $TestPath
$javauser | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Results" -Value $TestResult
$javauser | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Users" -Value $folder
#$javauser | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Users" -Value $users

$javausers += $javauser

$javausers | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path "C:\Temp\JavaUsersList.csv" -Append
```

Comment: PLEASE replace those two images of text with sanitized _text_. images are difficult to read and difficult to compare to test data.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey please explain sanitized text

Comment: sanitized text is text that has your private/proprietary data replaced with demo data. so that `John Jacob Jinglehimer Smith` becomes `John Fakename`, or `pc-nyc1-002` becomes `pc-abc1-002`. realistic, non-repetitive ... but not real.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey images are replaced

Comment: please reread the 1st sentence  of my 1st reply to your question. carefully note the `with sanitized _text_` and the `images are difficult to read ...` in the 2nd sentence. [*grin*] ///// DO NOT post images of text unless there is simply no other way to get the info across.

Comment: No, they aren't replaced with **text** and more important it's still unclear what output you expect. The `if($(try(Test-Path...` construct is IMO complete nonsense. Also the way you build $folder will never return an existing real path as $env:USERPROFILE will always represent the current logged in users path.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I cannot change the information otherwise. This information is already in images and I can't change that. I have tried to comply with your request. I think it is clear from the images and the information provided to address my question and provide assistance to do what I need to do.

Comment: @LotPings Thank you for the information. I wasn't aware of $env:USERPROFILE would always return the current logged in user. I am new to this and figuring it out as I go. How would I accomplish getting the output in a csv of each user and if that deployment.properties file is present. It should right to the csv TRUE or FALSE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read other users folders you'll need to RunsAsAdmin.

```
#Requires -RunAsAdministrator
## Q:\Test\2019\08\29\SO_57714265.ps1

Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass

$env:COMPUTERNAME = HostName

$DeplPath = "AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\deployment.properties"

$javausers = foreach ($User in Get-ChildItem C:\Users -Directory){
    $folder = Join-Path $User.FullName $DeplPath
    if (Test-Path $folder) {
        $TestResult = "True  - deployment.properties"
    } Else {
        $TestResult = "False - Path not found"
    }
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        "Computer Name" = $env:COMPUTERNAME
        "Results"       = $TestResult
        "Users"         = $user.Name
    }
}
$javausers

#$javausers | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path "C:\Temp\JavaUsersList.csv" -Append
```

Sample output:

```
Computer Name Results                       Users
------------- -------                       -----
VBoxWin10     False - Path not found        SomeOne
VBoxWin10     False - Path not found        Public
VBoxWin10     True  - deployment.properties LotPings
```

Comment: Thank you for the assistance. This is exactly what I need. Assuming that I haven't done research and testing, failing, and starting over isn't really helpful to anyone though.. I've been trying to figure this out for two weeks almost daily and trying everything I could find. I know the script works It just doesn't produce exactly what I need.